# ion-input type file only work on ios, not on android

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I have code like this
`<ion-input type="file" accept=".pdf,.doc,.docx" [(ngModel)]="data.files"></ion-input>`

and I try on ios it's work can choose file, but why not work on android? on android not have error, just when I click the button, the view scrolling down for sometimes and back to pervious view before scrolling down

Answer (score 1):

Input type=file won't work on mobile. Here is the reference 
https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/upload-file-with-input-type-file-but-get-it-with-file-path/100043/2

You can use cordova plugins like fileChooser, FilePicker-Phonegap-iOS-Plugin.